# How to update values in pandas dataframe in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a data frame that can store variable coeff value after each iteration. I am able to plot the graph after each iteration. but when I tried to insert the value in the data frame after each iteration.

I am getting this error.

> None of [Int64Index([ 3169,  3170,  3171,  3172,  3173,  3174,  3175,
>   3176,  3177,\n             3178,\n            ...\n            31671,
>   31672, 31673, 31674, 31675, 31676, 31677, 31678, 31679,\n
>   31680],\n           dtype='int64', length=28512)] are in the [columns]

This is the code I use:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
cvlasso= Lasso(alpha=0.001)
count = 1

var = pd.DataFrame()


for train, _ in kf.split(X, Y):
    cvlasso.fit(X.iloc[train, :], Y.iloc[train])
    importances_index_desc = cvlasso.coef_
    feature_labels = list(X.columns.values)
    importance = pd.Series(importances_index_desc, feature_labels)
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(feature_labels, importances_index_desc)
    plt.xticks(feature_labels, rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Importance')
    plt.xlabel('Features')
    plt.title('Fold {}'.format(count))
    count = count + 1
    var[train] = importances_index_desc

plt.show()
```

and one more thing there is a total of 33000 observations in my dataset but at the end of the loop, the train value is 28512? Does anyone know why train value is not 33000?

Answer (score 1):

`train` is the **list** of index of train data returned from KFold. You put `train` as accessing column in `var[train]` that will cause the error because none of index value is a DataFrame column .

IMO, setting complicated value as index is not good idea, just use simple value as index, for example

```
var.loc[count] = importances_index_desc
count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Instead of,

```
var = pd.DataFrame()
```

Create a dataframe with heading

```
var = pd.DataFrame(columns=['impt_idx_desc'])
```

Then in the loop use the 'loc' function as,

```
var.loc[count] = [importances_index_desc]
```

where count is increased by +1 in the loop.

Comment: Hi, use train as access index here will cause an error. You can check this for more detail: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: sorry, I overlooked the data type returned. Editing the answer now. Thanks!

Comment: still i am getting an error . Error = cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Comment: try var.loc[count] = [importances_index_desc]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using pandas.DataFrame.append(pandas.DataFrame):

```
important_index_desc = pd.DataFrame(important_index_desc)
var = var.append(important_index_desc)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: and one more thing there is a total of 33000 observations in my dataset but at the end of the loop, the train value is 28512? 
anyone know why train value is not 33000 ?

Comment: its possible that duplicate rows are removed on .append() - try .append(ignore_index=True)

Comment: yes but the train value starts from 0 right and move all the way up to the number of observation in the dataset. i.e. 31681, but my query is why it is 28512

Comment: from the error cited above in your question - it looks like it starts from 3169. it should start from zero. I think kf.split() gives a single value - like `for train in kf.split(X, Y)`